# The variable name '@Param' has already been declared

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm geting the following error message for given code when user clicks on search button more than two times. Could some one please help what i'm doing wrong.

> The variable name '@Param' has already
>   been declared. Variable names must be
>   unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DS.SelectCommand = 
      "SELECT ReportName, ReportType, 
       FROM Table 
       WHERE ReportName LIKE @param 
       ORDER BY ReportType Desc";
   DS.SelectParameters.Add("Param", searchTxtBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
   DS.DataBind();
   ListView1.DataBind();               
}
```

Comment: have you tried clearing out all of the `DS.SelectParameters` first? (before the `DS.SelectCommand` line) so its a new set of params each time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TRy

```
DS.SelectCommand = 
    "SELECT ReportName, ReportType, 
     FROM Table 
     WHERE ReportName LIKE @param 
     ORDER BY ReportType Desc";
DS.SelectParameters.Clear();
DS.SelectParameters.Add("Param", searchTxtBox.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
```

Comment: Thank you @Bala, i placed clear at the top and bottom not where you specified. Cheers! Works great!!

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see where `DS` is defined I can't be sure, but I suspect you're using the same datasource elsewhere with a different `Param`. Use a different source for each different query.