# The variable name '@ArrivedDate' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=NLA-HP;Initial Catalog=GTBDB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=dbadmin");

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Machine VALUES (@BranchName, @MachineName, @ArrivedDate, @FaultDetail, @ReturnDate, @Remark, @Technician)", connection);
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            //Variables declaration
            string BranchName = cbBranches.Text;
            string MachineName = txtbMachine.Text;
            DateTime ArrivedDate = dtpArrive.Value;
            string FaultDetail = rtxtbFault.Text;
            DateTime ReturnDate = dtpReturn.Value;
            string Remark = rtxtbRemark.Text;
            string Technician = txtbTechnician.Text;

            //Add values
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchName", BranchName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineName", MachineName);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivedDate", ArrivedDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaultDetail", FaultDetail);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReturnDate", ReturnDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remark", Remark);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technician", Technician);

            command.Parameters.Add("ArrivedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            command.Parameters.Add("ReturnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Successfully write to database", "Write to Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) //Catch exception
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Surely this is because you have both a `.AddWithValue("@ArrivedDate"` and `.Add("ArrivedDate` in your code? Why is it in there twice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you add 2 parameters twice:

First time

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivedDate", ArrivedDate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReturnDate", ReturnDate);
```

Second time

```
command.Parameters.Add("ArrivedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
command.Parameters.Add("ReturnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```

To give your parameter a SQL type and assign a value in one go, use:

```
command.Parameters.Add("ArrivedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ArrivedDate;
command.Parameters.Add("ReturnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ReturnDate;
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm beginner in programming. The second one is for converting SQL Data Type to DateTime. Isn't it? If I removed it, there will be Data Type miss match error?

Comment: I got it. Actually, we don't need to change SQL Type. I remove the second one and it successfully write to database. But I have one more question. I want date only, but it also include time. How can I remove time?

Comment: `ArrivedDate.Date`. But don't ask more than one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

I'll make it easy for you:

```
//Add values
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchName", BranchName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineName", MachineName);
/************************************************
  THIS LINE BELOW HERE HAS THE PARAMETER NAME
 ************************************************/
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivedDate", ArrivedDate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaultDetail", FaultDetail);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReturnDate", ReturnDate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remark", Remark);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technician", Technician);

/************************************************
  THIS LINE BELOW HERE HAS THE PARAMETER NAME TOO
 ************************************************/
command.Parameters.Add("ArrivedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
command.Parameters.Add("ReturnDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
```