# The variable name '@sno' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#

here is my code it will give following error.

The variable name '@sno' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

```
private void btnBatchInsert_Click(ArrayList data)
    {
        // Get the DataTable with Rows State as RowState.Added
         SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
       sqlcon.Open();

        for (int j = 0; j < data.Count; j++)
        {

            string[] arr = data[j].ToString().Split('#');


        // Set the Parameter with appropriate Source Column Name
            command.Parameters.Add("@sno",  arr[0].ToString());
        command.Parameters.Add("@IMECode",  arr[1].ToString());
        command.Parameters.Add("@rcptno",  arr[2].ToString());
        command.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceNo",  arr[3].ToString() );

        command.Parameters.Add("@CSSNo",  arr[4].ToString());
        command.Parameters.Add("@Invoicedate", arr[5].ToString());
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name",  arr[6].ToString());
        command.Parameters.Add("@PlanNo",   planMode(arr[7].ToString()) );

        command.Parameters.Add("@Mode",  PlanType(arr[8].ToString()));
        command.Parameters.Add("@Installamount", Convert.ToDouble(arr[9].ToString().Equals("") ? "0" : arr[9].ToString()).ToString());
        command.Parameters.Add("@Spotcommi",  Convert.ToDouble(arr[10].ToString().Equals("") ? "0" : arr[10].ToString()).ToString() );
        command.Parameters.Add("@Applicationfee", Convert.ToDouble(arr[11].ToString().Equals("") ? "0" : arr[11].ToString()).ToString());

        command.Parameters.Add("@Netamount",  (Convert.ToDouble(arr[12].ToString().Equals("") ? "0" : arr[12].ToString()) + Convert.ToDouble(arr[11].ToString().Equals("") ? "0" : arr[11].ToString())).ToString() );
        command.Parameters.Add("@Adjmount", Convert.ToDouble(arr[13].ToString().Equals("") ? "0" : arr[13].ToString()).ToString() );
        command.Parameters.Add("@csc_name", arr[14].ToString());

        command.Connection = sqlcon;
        //cmd.CommandText = "Insert into [Personal_information_ofcandidat](User_id,Name,MName,LName,Exam_date,Exam_id,College_Name,Email_id,Phone_no) values('" + userid + "','" + uname + "','" + muname + "','" + luname + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','" + examid + "','" + collegname + "','" + email + "','" + mobile + "')";

        command.CommandText = "insert into  tempforagreementlist(sno,IMECode,rcptno,InvoiceNo,CSSNo,Invoicedate,Name,PlanNo,Mode,Installamount,Spotcommi,Applicationfee,Netamount,Adjmount,csc_name) values(@sno,@IMECode,@rcptno,@InvoiceNo,@CSSNo,@Invoicedate,@Name,@PlanNo,@Mode,@Installamount,@Spotcommi,@Applicationfee,@Netamount,@Adjmount,@csc_name)";

        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


        int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }


    }
```

Comment: Which line gives error? Also error is compile or runtime error?

Comment: You are setting parameters in a loop for the command. Check if the parameter exist and only update the value if it does.

Comment: @ Nikhil Agrawal :- error accouters runtime at line "int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 4):

You are adding parameters inside a loop. The second, third, forth, etc iterations through the loop: yes, you will be adding duplicates.

Either:

- clear the parameters between iterations
- overwrite the values rather than adding new parameters

Answer (score 0):

You're adding all variables more than once.. because you're doing it in a loop.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(); // command that lasts 
                                       // across all iterations of loop

for (int j = 0; j < data.Count; j++) {
   // adding all parameters each time.
```

Add the parameters first.. then give them a value on each iteration (instead of doing both).

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration, you would need to create a new instance of SqlCommand and assign it to command for it to remove the parameters that you previously added.

```
  for (int j = 0; j < data.Count; j++)
        {
 command = new SqlCommand();
            string[] arr = data[j].ToString().Split('#');
```

Comment: Why would you open/close the connection each time? That's just bizarre

Comment: @MarcGravell yep, true - wouldn't be that nice. Let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution is to define the parameters outside the loop adding them to the Parameters collection. Inside the loop you change only the value and execute the command

Also try to be very specific with the Parameter type and size because in that way you allow the database engine to store the query plan and reuse it at every loop. This could be important in term of performances.

```
private void btnBatchInsert_Click(ArrayList data)
{
     sqlcon.Open();
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
     command.Connection = sqlcon;

     // Add to the parameters collection a specific parameter with appropriate type and size 
     command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sno",  SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32));
     ....
     for (int j = 0; j < data.Count; j++)
     {
         command.Parameters["@sno"].Value = arr[0].ToString();
         ....
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```