# The variable name '@OrderNo' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql

#### The variable name '@OrderNo' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Whenever i execute the code below, error comes on my sql parameters on second @OrderNo

```
 protected void lvProjects_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Literal ltOrderNo = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltOrderNo");

    if (e.CommandName == "startproj") 
    {

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Project " +
            "SET Status='On Going' , StartDate=@StartDate WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ltOrderNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }

    if (e.CommandName == "endproj")
    {
        #region

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Project " +
            "SET Status='Finished' , EndDate=@EndDate WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ltOrderNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        #endregion

        #region
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Deliveries VALUES (@OrderNo, @Status)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ltOrderNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Pending");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: This exception is throwing on the last `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` ?

Comment: Just clear parameters before redefining the insert query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the `cmd` SqlCommand object and in the second if-statement, you add the parameter called OrderNo twice. Solve this by [clearing out the parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.clear.aspx) after running the command (or maybe better: create a new SqlCommand for the second query).

```
if (e.CommandName == "endproj")
{

#region

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Project " +
        "SET Status='Finished' , EndDate=@EndDate WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ltOrderNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

#endregion

    //CLEAR PARAMETERS
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

#region

    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Deliveries VALUES (@OrderNo, @Status)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ltOrderNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Pending");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

#endregion

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create second `SqlCommand` as new one instead of trying to use the first one.

```
if (e.CommandName == "endproj")
{
    #region

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Project " +
        "SET Status='Finished' , EndDate=@EndDate WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo";
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ltOrderNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Now);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    #endregion

    #region
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Deliveries VALUES (@OrderNo, @Status)";
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", ltOrderNo.Text);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Pending");
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd1.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    #endregion
}
```