# The variable name '@Order_id' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#

I am getting this error when I insert data from a gridview, I am inserting data into order details where I want to save same order ID with every order item but could not. I am developing in C# windows. I have search the web but that couldn't solve my problem. I am stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.

I am adding my code lines that I am doing.

Kind regards

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = con.CreateCommand();
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT Top  1 *  FROM Purchase_Order Order By P_Order_ID desc";
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
sda2.Fill(dt);

int OrderID = 0;

foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
{
    OrderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["P_Order_ID"].ToString());

    MessageBox.Show("order id +" +OrderID);
}

SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand();
com2.Connection = con;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
    {
        OrderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["P_Order_ID"].ToString());
    }

    string Query;
    Query = @"INSERT INTO Purchase_Order_Detail (P_Order_ID, ProductID, PSC_ID, Pack_ID, Color, Base_ID, Quantity) VALUES (@OrderID, @ProductID, @Sub_ID, @PackID, @Colors, @BaseID, @Quantity);";

    // com2.Parameters.Add("@OrderID" & dataGridView1.Rows(i).ToString(), dataGridView1(i));

    com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderID", OrderID);
    com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sub_ID", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
    com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PackID", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
    com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Colors", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value);
    com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaseID", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value);
    com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value);

    com2.CommandText = Query;
    com2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //com2.Parameters.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Move `SqlCommand com2 = new ....` inside the for loop. Is it happening because you are trying to add orderid to same command object (Im second iteration onwards)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to re-add a parameter which is already added to the `SqlCommand`. In your case you should add the parameters (and the query) before the `for()` loop and then fill these parameters with the new values for execution.

```
SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand();
com2.Connection = con;
com2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Purchase_Order_Detail (P_Order_ID,ProductID,PSC_ID,Pack_ID,Color,Base_ID,Quantity) VALUES (@OrderID,@ProductID,@Sub_ID, @PackID,@Colors,@BaseID,@Quantity);";
com2.Parameters.Add("@OrderID", ...type...);
com2.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", ...type...);
com2.Parameters.Add("@Sub_ID", ...type...);
com2.Parameters.Add("@PackID", ...type...);
com2.Parameters.Add("@Colors", ...type...);
com2.Parameters.Add("@BaseID", ...type...);
com2.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", ...type...);
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr2 in dt.Rows)
    {
        OrderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["P_Order_ID"].ToString());
    }
    com2.Parameters["@OrderId"].Value = OrderId;
    com2.Parameters["@ProductID"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;  
    ...        

    com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Hi progman, thanks for the response. I want to know what i have to write in "..Type.." ? data type of parameter that  i have set in SQL?

Comment: @OsamaHassan Yes. The Java API cannot know what the types are without any value so you have specify the type for the parameter.