# The variable name '@fname' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to save data from LIST to SQL Server, but the error is :

> The variable name '@fname' has already been declared

Here is my code :

```
public void Save()
{
    string insert = "Insert into Professor (fname, lname, dateOfBirth, gender, country, email, mdp) Values (@fname, @lname, @dateOfBirth, @gender, @country, @email, @mdp) ";

    SqlCommand vide = new SqlCommand("Truncate table Professor", mode);

    // Save data from LIST to SERVER
    mode.Open();

    // Truncate the Table
    vide.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Save all data to SQL Server
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, mode);

    for(int i = 0; i < pf.Count; i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", pf[i].fname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", pf[i].lname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfBirth", pf[i].dateOfBirth);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", pf[i].sexe);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", pf[i].country);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", pf[i].email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mdp", pf[i].password);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    mode.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Your compte has been added!");
}
```

and this is my upload function to save all data from sql to list

```
public void Upload()
{
    pf.Clear();
    mode.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Professor", mode);

    SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
       Professor p = new Professor(myReader["fname"].ToString(), myReader["lname"].ToString(),Convert.ToDateTime(myReader["dateOfBirth"].ToString()),myReader["country"].ToString(),myReader["gender"].ToString(),myReader["email"].ToString(),myReader["mdp"].ToString());
       pf.Add(p);
    }

    mode.Close();
}
```

By the way, I put truncate just to avoid problem of repeated data because of primary key, that's why I have saved all sql data to my list, and in this function I want to add new data so as to save clean data to my SQL Server.

How can I solve that?

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: You are trying to add parameters to command in loop. This will cause the same parameters to be added multiple times that's why you are getting this error. You should add parameters outside the loop and just set their values in the loop.

Comment: **Chetan Ranpariya** but how can I do that, give me an example please!!

Comment: If you read the words in the error message, they explain the problem very clearly. On the first pass through the loop, you add the parameters. On every pass after that, they already exist and you can't add them again. Error messages aren't just there to take up space on your screen. They provide information about the problem, but you actually have to read them to make use of that information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to add parameters to command in loop. This will cause the same parameters to be added multiple times that's why you are getting this error. You should add parameters outside the loop and just set their values in the loop.

Have the `Save` method changed as following.

```
public void Save()
{
    string insert = "Insert into Professor (fname,lname,dateOfBirth,gender,country,email,mdp) Values(@fname,@lname,@dateOfBirth,@gender,@country,@email,@mdp) ";
    SqlCommand vide = new SqlCommand("Truncate table Professor", mode);
    //Save data from LIST to SERVER
    mode.Open();
    //Truncate the Table
    vide.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Save All data to SQL
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, mode);
    //Add parameters to the command
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateOfBirth", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    // Not sure what value you are storing for gender so setting type to VarChar  
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@country", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mdp", SqlDbType.VarChar);

    //Setting values of parameters and execute the command
    for(int i=0;i<pf.Count;i++)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@fname"].Value = pf[i].fname;
        cmd.Parameters["@lname"].Value = pf[i].lname;
        cmd.Parameters["@dateOfBirth"].Value = pf[i].dateOfBirth;
        cmd.Parameters["@gender"].Value = pf[i].sexe;
        cmd.Parameters["@country"].Value = pf[i].country;
        cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = pf[i].email;
        cmd.Parameters["@mdp"].Value = pf[i].password;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    mode.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Your compte has been added!");
}
```