# The variable name '@ID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sqlcommand

I have built a search function that will be searching by ID and by last name.

This is my code so far:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [ID],[Name],[LastName],[FirstName],[FinalGrade] FROM DATABASE WHERE ID = @ID OR LastName = @lname");

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lname",lname);

    /*if (ID == null)
    {
        unitsParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }*/

    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DBNull.Value);
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lname))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", DBNull.Value);
    }

    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                int i = 0;

                // vm.SearchResults.Add(new ApqcrDirSearch
                ApqcrDirModel aRec = new ApqcrDirModel();

                aRec.ID = sdr.IsDBNull(i) ? null : sdr.GetString(i);
                i++;

                aRec.Name = sdr.IsDBNull(i) ? null : sdr.GetString(i);
                i++;

                aRec.LastName = sdr.IsDBNull(i) ? null : sdr.GetString(i);
                i++;

                aRec.FirstName = sdr.IsDBNull(i) ? null : sdr.GetString(i);
                i++;

                vm.SearchResults.Add(aRec);
            }
        }

        con.Close();
}
```

How do I search by both ID and LastName ? Do I have to use `SqlCommandParameter`? If yes, how ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding your parameters twice. Instead of using `AddWithValue`, use `Add`, and then you can check if `ID` or `Name` are null or empty, like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    .Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID) ? (object)DBNull.Value : ID;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    .Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lname) ? (object)DBNull.Value : lname;
```

Note: I'm guessing `VarChar`, might be a different type.

Answer (score 2):

can use

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

after   `con.Open();`

it will be clear other parameters

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are receiving the errormessage: `"The variable name '@ID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure"`
Is because you are declaring the parameter `@ID` twice. You are also declaring the `@lname` parameter twice. Remove the following code from your method and the error should not appear again:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DBNull.Value);
}

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lname))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", DBNull.Value);
}
```

The above code does not make sense to implement. You should check if the lastname and the id parameters are empty before you enter the method. Think of it like input validation.

Comment: I removed that part of code, now its giving me this error : The parameterized query '(@ID nvarchar(4000),@lname nvarchar(4000))SELECT [ID],[Name],[La' expects the parameter '@ID', which was not supplied.