# SQL exception incorrect syntax near 'G' what's the problem?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

I have a SQL query created by inserting values from C#.

In C#:

```
string command = "INSERT INTO Phones (devicename, batterylife, price, antutu, ImageURL) 
                  VALUES (" + model + ", " + batterylife + ", " + price + ", " + antutu + ", " + imgURL + " )";
```

In SQL after parsing:

```
INSERT INTO Phones (devicename, batterylife, price, antutu, ImageURL) 
VALUES ( Samsung-Galaxy-S10-5G, 0, 0, 0, 
         cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s10-5g.jpg )
```

and when trying to execute it, Visual Studio throws the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=Incorrect syntax near 'G'.
>   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider

Also when I replace the regular model name variable with a word Visual Studio throws the same exception for little g with no location help to understand.

Comment: Missing quotes, `VALUES ( 'Samsung-Galaxy-S10-5G', 0, 0, 0, 'cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s10-5g.jpg' )`. However, you should use parameters instead of substituting text!

Comment: Don't do this, use parameters. Search up on SQL injection and how to avoid it -- parameters prevent this, among other things.

Comment: Imagine what would happed if `'); drop table Phones;--` was passed as a URL. Don't use string concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have indicated, you are using string concatenation to build your SQL command, which will enable SQL injection in your code.

Please use the following pattern instead which relies on parameters and therefore is not susceptible to this attack:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
...
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    cn.Open();

    using (var cm = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cm.CommandText =
            "INSERT INTO Phones (devicename, batterylife, price, antutu, ImageURL) " +
            "VALUES (@devicename, @batterylife, @price, @antutu, @ImageURL)";

        cm.Parameters.Add("@devicename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "Samsung-Galaxy-S10-5G";
        cm.Parameters.Add("@batterylife", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        cm.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        cm.Parameters.Add("@antutu", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        cm.Parameters.Add("@ImageURL", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1).Value = "cdn2.gsmarena.com/vv/bigpic/samsung-galaxy-s10-5g.jpg";

        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

You must adjust the size/type of each `SqlParameter` as needed.

Comment: thnx mate that solved it! but as far as syntax goes why did my solution have a problem (besides the security one)? also had to add cmd.Parameters.Clear(); to repeat the process in a loop

Comment: Your `devicename` and `ImageURL` columns seems to be of `varchar` type, your SQL was incorrect because when providing a literal string you must enclosed it between quotes, e.g. 'Samsung-Galaxy-S10-5G'; @jarlh mentioned this in your question. Also, instead of doing `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` inside your loop, consider assigning a variable name for each `SqlParameter` instead, that way inside your loop you just set the values to the each parameter and then call `cm.ExecuteNonQuery();`, this will be more appropriate than destroying them and creating them every time.

Comment: Take a look at the following link, I think it applies to what you are doing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: thnx, for any one interested the following link help with the second problem I had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w