# Data transfer between DataTable and Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a data table that is implemented with a DataTable. The task is to pass the data of each cell to a Sql Server table. I'm trying to implement this with the code below:

```cs
Task AddToDB = Task.Run(() =>
{
  for (int i = 0; i < DataTableView.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < DataTableView.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {

      try
      {
        sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TestTable  VALUES (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3)";
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        //sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1",  DataTableView.Rows[i][j]);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2", DataTableView.Rows[i][j]);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value3", DataTableView.Rows[i][j]);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
      }
    }
  }

});

return AddToDB;
```

The error is that after the first iteration I get an error:
`The variable name '@Value1' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.`

I tried to study this answer carefully
[The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure. in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w/19535530#19535530)
 and add a line

```cs
sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

but in the end I got another error

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Value'
```

The value of the variable is zeroed, and in the database settings it is specified that the value of cells can not be empty. How can I bypass these limitations and write data to the database?

Comment: User-Defined Table Type is an ideal for your requirement. You don't need to loop through. Entire dataset can be sent in one go

Comment: @ChathurangaRanasinghe can I ask for a link with a good description of User-Defined? Some of the first links on google didn't give me a clear idea of how it works.

Comment: Check this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/user-defined-table-types-and-table-valued-parameters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-initialize the `sqlCommand.Parameters` inside the for loop. The current problem is that the array of parameters for that particular command (`sqlCommand.Parameters`) gets a duplicated parameter name on the 2nd iteration because it still has the previous ones.

The solution you linked should be enough. Just clear the parameters immediately before setting them up:

```
for (int j = 0; j < DataTableView.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
{

    try
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TestTable  VALUES (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3)";
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value1",  DataTableView.Rows[i][j]);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value2",  DataTableView.Rows[i][j]);
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value3",  DataTableView.Rows[i][j]);

        sqlConnection.Open();
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

Also make sure to add the `TestTable` column names and proper order on the `INSERT` statement:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TestTable (Column1, Column2, Column3)  VALUES (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3)";
```

Comment: I'm guaranteed to get an error since the server will assume I'm inserting an empty value. ```c# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Value'```

Comment: Then either remove the `NOT NULL` definition on your table, or skip the row when the cell value is null.

Answer (score 0):

Call AddWithValue just once (or better still, [use something else](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)) outside the loop, then set just the value inside the loop:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", -1); //dummy value of same type as ID is
foreach(var ro in table.Rows){
  cmd.Parameters["id"].Value = (int)ro["PersonID"];
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It's a simplified example to demonstrate the point. I don't recommend clearing the parameters and re-adding them each time, as advocated in EzLo's answer

Actually, you should consider using a DataAdapter, as it it knows how to do this already..

..and then you should probably *actually* use strongly typed datasets and tableadapters to persist your changes to the database. When you generate a strongly type DataTable that is linked with a db table, it comes with a dedicated TableAdapter that is responsible for filling the rows from the db and updating the changes. A read, update, write cycle might look like:

```
var ta = new PersonTableAdapter();
var dt = ta.GetDataById(123);
dt.Rows[0].Name = "John Smith";
ta.Update(dt); //it saves the changes to the db; new rows are Inserted, changed rows UPDATEd and removed rows are DELETEd
```