# 'The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.'

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework

```
string subject=  "INSERT INTO Subjects (ThesisNo, [Subject]) VALUES (2, @subject)";
      
SqlCommand commandSubject = new SqlCommand(subject,con);

string temp;

foreach (var control in checkedListBox.CheckedItems) 
{
    temp = control.ToString();
    commandSubject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", temp);
}

con.Open();
commandSubject.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I want to add items that are checked in the Checkedlistbox to `@subject`.

But I can only add one item. How can I add all checked items to `@subject`?

Comment: You are adding all your parameters in your look to the same variable @subject.  That is where your error is.  Depending on what you mean by add all the checkboxes to subject?  Do you want them all concatenated into one string then insert?  Then build out the string to concat in the loop then do the update.

Comment: an @subject must be added for each item

Comment: How many possible items and is the number likely to change very often?

Comment: @Charlieface one or more than one item can select each time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're adding parameters inside the loop. Add outside, and set the value inside and execute every time:

```
    using(SqlConnection con = ...) {
        string subject=  "INSERT INTO Subjects(ThesisNo,[Subject]) VALUES (2, @subject)";
        con.Open();
        
        SqlCommand commandSubject = new SqlCommand(subject,con);
        commandSubject.Parameters.Add("@subject", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        foreach (var control in checkedListBox.CheckedItems) 
        {
            commandSubject.Parameters["@subject"].Value = control.ToString();
            commandSubject.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Or if you're wanting to execute once you need to modify the SQL, and add as you go, so that you end up with an SQL like e.g. `INSERT INTO .. VALUES (2,@p0), (2,@p1), (2,@p2)` and a parameters collection that is 3 long (@p0 to @p2) with 3 different data values:

```
    using(SqlConnection con = ...) {
        string subject=  "INSERT INTO Subjects(ThesisNo,[Subject])VALUES";
        
        
        SqlCommand commandSubject = new SqlCommand(subject, con);
        
        int p=0;
        foreach (var control in checkedListBox.CheckedItems) 
        {
            commandSubject.CommandText += $"(2,@subject{p}),"
            commandSubject.Parameters.Add($"@subject{p}", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = control.ToString();
            p++;
        }

        commandSubject.CommandText = commandSubject.CommandText.TrimEnd(','); //remove trailing comma from concat

        con.Open();
        commandSubject.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

If you have thousands of these string concats to do, use a StringBuilder. For what you might reasonably want a user to tick in a UI (20 or fewer?) string concat will be fine

Answer (score 0):

The best method depends on whether the number of items is large and variable.

If that is the case either a Table-Valued Parameter or using `SqlBulkCopy` is the most performant option.

Here is how you would do `SqlBulkCopy`:

```cs
var table = new DataTable{
    Columns = {
        {"ThesisNo", typeof(int)},
        { "Subject", typeof(string)
    }
};

foreach (var control in checkedListBox.CheckedItems)
    DataTable.Rows.Add(2, control.ToString());

using(var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints | SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers)
{
    DestinationTableName  = "Subjects"
})
    bulk.WriteToServer(table);
```

---

The other method, which, at a push, you can get away with on smaller sets, is to add a numbered parameter for each item. **The maximum is 2100**. Do **NOT** do this if range of possible rowcounts is large, otherwise you will kill your query plan store:

```cs
using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("",con))
{
    var n = 0;
    foreach (var control in checkedListBox.CheckedItems)
        comm.Parameters.Add("@subject" + (++n), SqlDbType.Varchar, *sizeofcolumnhere*).Value = control.ToString();

    comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Subjects(ThesisNo,[Subject])\r\nVALUES\r\n" +
        string.Join("\r\n",
            Enumerable.Range(1, n).Select(i => $"(2 ,@subject{i})");
    
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Small curio about the "smaller sets" thing; I recently saw Dan Guzman advocate sending nearly a million values this way..

Comment: Please provide a reference for that, maybe @DanGuzman can say. Max params is 2000 I believe. And once you get to a few hundred or 1000, BCP will blow it away.

Comment: Well that's a headscratcher for me because I recently debugged an issue where a long running service erroneously using a singleton dbcontext had accumulated 2900 parameters for an INSERT because the first entity in the graph was causing a PK violation, so it'd just been plugging away, adding more and more new entities and failing each SaveChanges... Removing the DB side conflict made them all go away.. I'll test it

Comment: Misremembered exact number. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) say 2100 is the max. The other big issue, which I didn't make clear is that if the number is varying, a new query plan is generated for each run. Have clarified

Comment: 2100 (sqlazure) indeed:  *System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The incoming request has too many parameters. The server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters. Reduce the number of parameters and resend the request.*

Answer (score -1):

Add the line 'SqlCommand commandSubject = new SqlCommand(subject,con)' to the foreach loop:

```
string subject=  "INSERT INTO Subjects (ThesisNo, [Subject]) VALUES 
(2, @subject)";
  
string temp;

foreach (var control in checkedListBox.CheckedItems) 
{
SqlCommand commandSubject = new SqlCommand(subject,con);
temp = control.ToString();
commandSubject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", temp);
}

con.Open();
commandSubject.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: This is wrong and is the problem OP is trying to _solve_, not repeat.