# The variable name '@Personnel_Number' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to show Employee Name on basis of Personal_No but while doing I got error

> The variable name '@Personnel_Number' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure

My code:

```
protected void txtEmployeeNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string EmployeeNo = "";
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDBConnection"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Employee_Name from [138.201.225.134].[iProfile].[dbo].[tbl_Employee] WHERE Personnel_Number= @Personnel_Number", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            EmployeeNo = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;
        }
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Personnel_Number", EmployeeNo);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            (row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName1") as TextBox).Text = dt.Rows[0]["Employee_Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

If i tried to keep (row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName1") as TextBox).Text = dt.Rows[0]["Employee_Name"].ToString(); out side of foreach loop then error occurs on row

Please guide me what should i change in this code 
I am getting error on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); while my loop runs 2nd time.
My text box are inside the Grid view

Comment: There is a loop which add `@Personnel_Number` multiple times.... As the error says... Move it all in the loop.

Comment: yes while loop runs second time error occurs but how can i fix it? even i can't place executenonqury() outside the loop

Comment: Place `SqlCommand cmd = ...` in the loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The variable name '@Param' has already been declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152646/the-variable-name-param-has-already-been-declared)

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Clear() at the beginning of your loop

Comment: @bradbury9 you mean after cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

Comment: @NitsPatel Check my answer, not only I show it but also give an advice on that function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The variable name '@' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535486/the-variable-name-has-already-been-declared-variable-names-must-be-unique-w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate the command inside the loop:

```
    protected void txtEmployeeNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string EmployeeNo = "";
        string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);

        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                EmployeeNo = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Employee_Name from [138.201.225.134].[iProfile].[dbo].[tbl_Employee] WHERE Personnel_Number= @Personnel_Number", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Personnel_Number", EmployeeNo);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                (row.Cells[2].FindControl("txtEmployeeName1") as TextBox).Text = dt.Rows[0]["Employee_Name"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This solution creates a `SqlCommand` object for every row which may negatively affect performance.

Comment: @NitsPatel I have added a description of what you were doing wrong to my answer, hope it helps you understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `Clear` method at the end of each iteration. Try.like:

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear(); <--Add it at the end of loop
```

Or alternatively you can palce the code that initializes the SQlCOmmand inside the for loop, so you will always have a new parameter. Something like:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Employee_Name from [138.201.225.134].[iProfile].[dbo].[tbl_Employee] WHERE Personnel_Number= @Personnel_Number", con);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  ....
```

Comment: i already try this cmd.Parameters.Clear(); but still its showing

Answer (score 2):

Add the parameter before entering the loop, then change the value as you loop through each row:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Personnel_Number", SqlDbType.VarChar));

foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
{
     //get EmployeeNo code

     cmd.Parameters["@Personnel_Number"].Value = EmployeeNo;    

     //rest of your code
}
```

HTH

Comment: I like how you add the `SqlParameter`, but I wonder how you knew it was string...

Comment: @bradbury9 I don't know that but I would think the dev would be able to know their data types and assign accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `Add()` or `AddWithValue()` inside the loop but the `SqlCommand` is outside it, on the second iteration it would try to add another parameter with the same parameter name.

Do note that I would choose the former rather than the later, and you [should consider stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

You should either:

```
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Personnel_Number", SqlDbType.[Your SQL Type]));
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                EmployeeNo = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;
            }
            cmd.Parameters["@Personnel_Number"].Value = EmployeeNo;
            con.Open();
            // rest of your loop
        }
```

or

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                EmployeeNo = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;
            }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Personnel_Number", EmployeeNo);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            con.Close();
            // rest of your loop
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @apomene you can solve your problem by adding following single line in start of each iteration as below sample

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grdRegister.Rows)
{
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
//Do rest of work
}
```

But IMHO you don't need to do the following**

```
 con.Open();
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

You can simply **pass command to data adapter and you will get data** in data table using fill function.

Answer (score -2):

You're doing some things wrong.

-- Update: I was wrong too! Thanks to @Polyfun for clearing that out for me.

#### 1) You shouldn't update inside of the textbox edit event.

Move your code to a button. Execute SQL query every time you enter a character isn't that good.

#### 2) You're searching for control in a loop.

```
EmployeeNo = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("txtEmployeeNumber") as TextBox).Text;
```

Find it once outside the loop - it will speed up whole process.

#### Regarding your question, you're parsing database response manually. Why?

Try using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)! It can automatically builds native C# objects from database response!
It supports variables and provides protection from [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you're [using it right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13664493/12030195).
Here's a [documentation](https://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper) for it.
Also you can use [Dapper Extensions](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions) for better experience.

Answers above me are kinda right, but using Dapper you don't have to control where you add parameters and where you remove them.

Here's an example for Dapper:

```
var result = connection.Query<SomeClass>("select * from SomeTable where UserId = @userId", new { userId });
```

Pretty simple, huh?

Comment: Lets do a workaround instead making OP realize the wrong logic so he/she could learn...

Comment: 1 is bad advice - for scaling you should minimise the scope of SqlConnections, and rely on the default connection pooling, as per Microsoft's recommendations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8.

Comment: @Polyfun Oh. Didn't know that! Thank you for clearing that out for me.

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: @bradbury9 I guess you're right, but OP can avoid problems like these using a library. Why reinvent wheel?